# Shutdown removes account on Android 4

Tags: android, shutdown, accountmanager

after installing my app and logging in, the application stores an account that I need for future operations. The problem is that after I reboot the tablet that account is not present. From what i've read the problem is that Android 4 clears all accounts for tha applications installed in the sd-card, so i added installLocation="internalOnly" in my manifest to force the installation on the internal memory.
The app in now installing in the internal memory but the issue is still verifying.

Suggestions?

Comment: You need to store account information in shared preference.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use SharedPrefrences like:

```
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

To store data:

```
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(BOOLEAN_VAR, false);others data types
    editor.apply();
```

To read data:

```
    boolean mydata = settings.getBoolean(BOOLEAN_VAR, true);
```

There are a lot of getXXX() and setXXX() for differente data types.

Comment: This is what i read from the Log:  and  D/AccountManagerService(193): deleting account tablet1@company.com (CompanyApp) because type company.package no longer has a registered authenticator. Why android is doing this?

Comment: Are you suggesting me to store the account object in the shared preferences and get it after the reboot?

Comment: The log is saying i the package has no registered authenticator because Android is removning it! From the same Log: D/PackageManager(193):   Service removed: AuthenticatorDescription {type=company.package}   Can i prevent this operation?

Comment: You could just store the credentials (user/passwd or whatever) and recover them after reboot if you are not authenticated.

Comment: For the account deletion problem, seems like the accountType you used on the account creation isn't available at this point. Could you post some code?

Comment: @DiegoLucaccini did you find a solution to this problem? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @RaB I noticed this log at startup: "D/AccountManagerService(193): deleting account -----@-----.com (appname) because type account.account no longer has a registered authenticator". We solved in a drastic way: we contacted the tablet manufacturer and they made a custom version of the OS. But yes I know this is not a viable solution.

Comment: I managed to solve the issue by forcing the app onto the internal memory.

    android:installLocation="internalOnly"